# Square Root formula in Calculator

Tags: android, kotlin, expression, calculator

Ok I am having an issue trying to put a square root equation in a calculator. I am trying to figure out the expression builder. I know the expression builder takes the math operations of add, subtract, multiply, divide, equals and the parenthesis. What I am doing is trying to build the square root section. I have a simple Percent code to help with the square root.

In the Square root vs the Percent you see I am using binding. So here is the code for both.

On the square root is it possible to use the expression builder? I know there is no absolute formula for square root except for a number that is multipliable with itself like the number 4.

> Sqrt(4) = 2

```
binding.btnSqrt.setOnClickListener {
var square = (tv_equation.text.toString().toDouble() / 2)
binding.tvResult.text = square.toString()
}
```

So in the event you a non square equation

> sqrt(23) = 4.79

How would I simulate that as one function within the button. Can I use expression or would I need to use `Kotlin.math`

So between the two I divide by 100 on the percent. It works great.

```
binding.btnPercent.setOnClickListener {
var percentage = (tv_equation.text.toString().toDouble() / 100)
binding.tvResult.text = percentage.toString()
}
```

All my other buttons work fine and so I am just working on the square root before I can release this to google play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use some form of a square root function.
AS you mentioned in your question [Kotlin Sqrt Function](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.math/sqrt.html) is a very suitable choice

```
binding.btnSqrt.setOnClickListener {
if(!tv_equation.text.isNullOrEmpty){
var number = tv_equation.text.toString().toDouble()
binding.tvResult.text = sqrt(number).toString()
}
```

You can create a sqrt function using the Quake's first inverse square root.
[Quake's first inverse square root](https://betterexplained.com/articles/understanding-quakes-fast-inverse-square-root/).

Pseudo Code:

```
    float InvSqrt(float x){
        float xhalf = 0.5f * x;
        int i = *(int*)&x;            // store floating-point bits in integer
        i = 0x5f3759df - (i >> 1);    // initial guess for Newton's method
        x = *(float*)&i;              // convert new bits into float
        x = x*(1.5f - xhalf*x*x);     // One round of Newton's method
        return x;
    }
```

Comment: that worked. But on a deeper level how would do that say if your programming a .dll with that function. I know it is reinventing the wheel. But if I wanted to have my own library of math functions. This worked but for reference how would I do it from scratch.

Comment: Added the code to implement the square root from scratch

Comment: I appreciate it. I also answered and expanded my own solution so maybe it will help someone in the future.

Comment: Sure thing man ..:).. yeah adding the decimal values is a good practice. :)

Comment: @Narenda_Nath now I am just working on the scroll on textview I am stumped on it but I posted a question about it

Answer (score 0):

So the answer i want to add is a little more suitable with the previous answer. Maybe this will help some people in the future. This solution will also limit the decimal space to 4 decimals.

```
binding.btnSqrt.setOnClickListener{
        val df = DecimalFormat("#.####")
        if(!tv_equation.text.isNullOrEmpty())
        {
            val number = tv_equation.text.toString().toDouble()
            binding.tvResult.text = df.format(sqrt(number))
        }
    }
```

you can adjust the `val df = DecimalFormat("#.####")` where the `#` to as many decimals as you would want.